# Android MediaProjection screen mirroring to Web browser over USB

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaprojection

I want to mirror Android Screen to desktop web browser. I am able to capture the screen using MediaProjection - thanks to sample app.

But next part is hard one - sending captured data to desktop! I know the technique to establish HTTP connection to desktop program by ADB port forwarding but I guess FPS will be very low.

How can I stream this captured screen data to desktop? What sort of connection would I need and what codecs would I need on Android side to ensure speed?

Thanks

Comment: The `screenrecord` v1.2 shell command can be used to stream H.264 over ADB. I successfully piped it into vlc on a Linux system, though I'm afraid I didn't save the command line arguments to vlc. ADB is pretty slow, but you can cap the maximum bit rate with the video encoder configuration. The trick is to configure the tty for raw data -- see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/marshmallow-mr1-release/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp#487

Comment: @fadden I am trying to build a Java solution. Something like [vysor.io](http://www.vysor.io/). Its based on MediaProjection but not sure of streaming part. Any hints?

Comment: Is It for debug or capture?